# Why isn't MenuInflater Responding?

Tags: android, if-statement, menu, menuitem, inflate

I am a noob to android and i am trying to inflate two different menus depending on user selection.  However, the menu isn't switching.  The same menu inflates everytime regardless of what the user selects.  I've tried and checked my if/else statmente with various parameters and the menu inflater still doesn't respond properly by only inflating the same menu.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    popUpMenu = getMenuInflater();
    //popUpMenu.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
    if(mypodcast==null){
        popUpMenu.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
    }else  {
        popUpMenu.inflate(R.menu.podcast, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The same menu inflates everytime regardless of what the user selects.

That is because `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is not called each time you open the menu, from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29):

> This is only called once, the first time the options menu is displayed. To update the menu every time it is displayed, see [onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

If you want to change menus you need to do this in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. However I don't believe that you can or should inflate a new menu every time `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is called. But you can combine the two menus and change the visibility of each menu item according to what you want in this method.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  You just schooled me.

Comment: Glad I could help teach you, schooled sounds a little harsh. Perhaps you simply confused the ContextMenu with the OptionsMenu, since `onCreateContextMenu()` _is_ called every time the menu opens...